# Doing a string replace

Tags: c, reinventing-the-wheel

How does the following look for doing a string replace in C? Is this approach more common than allocating memory within the function and returning a new string pointer, or is the bring-your-own-buffer more common?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


// return size of string, -1 if error such as buffer too small
// no memory is allocated here, buffer needs to be passed in
// Example: str_replace("Replace me", "me", "ME", buffer, 64);
// Returns: 10, buffer is now "Replace ME".
ssize_t 
str_replace (
        const char* input_str, 
        const char* from, 
        const char* to, 
        char* output_buffer, 
        size_t max_size
) {
    size_t input_len = strlen(input_str);
    size_t from_size = strlen(from);
    size_t to_size = strlen(to);

    // get the output string length;
    size_t output_len = input_len;
    char* str_iterator = (char*) input_str;
    while ((str_iterator=strstr(str_iterator, from))) {
        output_len += (to_size - from_size);
        str_iterator += from_size;
    }
    if (output_len > max_size) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Buffer too small for output string.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // reset str_iterator, make sure output_buffer is clear
    str_iterator = (char*) input_str;
    output_buffer[0] = '\0';

    // copy to output buffer
    // 1. Find the first match of `from` in `input_str` (advancing pointer on input_buffer along way)
    // 2. Copy the input_str up until the first match to output_buffer
    // 3. Copy `from` into output_buffer (advance string)
    // 4. Advance input_buffer pointer by size of `from`
    // 5. Repeat 2-5 until no more matches
    // 6. Copy remainder of input_str to output_buffer
    for (char* match; (match=strstr(str_iterator, from)); str_iterator+= (match-str_iterator) + from_size) {
        strncpy(output_buffer, str_iterator, match-str_iterator);
        output_buffer += (match-str_iterator);
        strncpy(output_buffer, to, to_size);
        output_buffer += to_size;
    }
    // copy remainder
    if (strlen(str_iterator))
        strcpy(output_buffer, str_iterator);

    return output_len;
}
```

```
int main(void)
{
    char buffer[50];
    ssize_t out_size = str_replace("Replace me", "me", "ME", buffer, 50);
    if (out_size == -1)
        printf("Nope!\n");
    else
        printf("Response size: %zu.\nResponse string: %s\n", out_size, buffer);
}
```

> $ gcc logmain.c -o log; ./log 
> Response size: 10. 
> Response string: Replace ME

And another alternative:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// same as above but now with malloc
char* str_replace2(const char* input, const char* from, const char* to)
{
    size_t input_len = strlen(input);
    size_t from_size = strlen(from);
    size_t to_size = strlen(to);
    char* str_iterator = (char*) input;

    // get the output string length;
    size_t output_len = input_len;
    while ((str_iterator=strstr(str_iterator, from))) {
        output_len += (to_size - from_size);
        str_iterator += from_size;
    }
    char *str_out = malloc(output_len);
    char * const str_out_start = str_out; // const for emphasis it doesn't change
    if (!str_out) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot malloc str of size %zu", output_len);
        return NULL;
    }

    // write to output str
    str_iterator = (char*) input;
    for (char* match; (match=strstr(str_iterator, from)); str_iterator+= (match-str_iterator) + from_size) {
        strncpy(str_out, str_iterator, match-str_iterator);
        str_out += (match-str_iterator);
        strncpy(str_out, to, to_size);
        str_out += to_size;
    }
    // copy remainder
    if (strlen(str_iterator))
        strcpy(str_out, str_iterator);

    return str_out_start;
}
```

Additionally, where are comments usually put in C? Above the function? In the function?

Comment: What about not passing a string? or something not properly terminated?

Answer (score 2):

Few things to consider.

0. Why are you writing your own implementation of something that already exists, long history of reliable use with well defined behaviour (fun/assignment - sure, generally - waste of effort likely to lead to problems)?
1. What if `input`, `from`, or `to` are null, or not valid (not `\0` terminated), OR overlap in any way (will it work)?
2. `from` and `to`, might imply to some people replace from here, to there.  Names are important - look for things that are self-evident.  Perhaps `matchToReplace` and `replaceMatchWith` - a bit wordy, but hopefully less ambiguous.
3. What happens if `from` is empty - what is the sensible result (document it)?
4. Don't you need to malloc one more than the desired length (for the terminating `\0`) [didn't read the algorithm carefully enough sorry].
5. Make sure you have test cases checking all the above, but also confirming that when you copy 0 length things, or 1 - that everything is copied properly.
6. Documenting - what tool are you using to publish it?  Certainly doesn't hurt to put a comment before - but remember what people are looking at is the headers - for the declaration, not the implementation (generally at least).

Comment: "Why are you writing your own implementation..." I'm a beginner in C and just practicing doing things. Reading others code and implementing things, etc.

Comment: maybe this is a bit too much to ask, but would you be able to suggest solutions for 1-7. It can even be a sentence without any code, just some ideas for when I implement all your suggestions. For example, what are choices for doing `tests` or `documenting` ?